# Is there a way to create an Azure Data Science VM using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-dsvm

I am using Terraform to create Azure VMs, but since those don't have much functionality installed, I was investigating on other Azure resources. I found the Azure Data Science VM is the one that covers most of my requirements, so I was wondering if there is a way to create those with Terraform. I can't see it in the documentation, but maybe there is a workaround.

Any orientation on this would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assumption**

Azure Resource Model.

**Steps**

There will be several steps to this process. You'll firstly need to retrieve a platform image.

```
data "azurerm_platform_image" "test" {
   location  = "West Europe"
   publisher = "Microsoft"
   offer     = "xx"
   sku       = "xx"
}
```

Before you can fully populate this however, you will need to retrieve the `SKU` and `Offer`. Annoyingly, this isn't readily available on the internet and requires an API call or Powershell fun.

[This](http://www.florisvanderploeg.com/available-vm-sizes-and-images-in-azure-per-location/) link will help you achieve this.

Once you've got the above terraform populated, you can then utilise this to create a virtual machine.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "test" {
    name                  = "acctvm"
    location              = "West US 2"
    resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.test.id}"]
    vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

storage_image_reference {
    id = "${data.azurerm_platform_image.test.id}"
}

storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
}

# Optional data disks
storage_data_disk {
    name              = "datadisk_new"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    create_option     = "Empty"
    lun               = 0
    disk_size_gb      = "1023"
}

storage_data_disk {
    name            = "${azurerm_managed_disk.test.name}"
    managed_disk_id = "${azurerm_managed_disk.test.id}"
    create_option   = "Attach"
    lun             = 1
    disk_size_gb    = "${azurerm_managed_disk.test.disk_size_gb}"
}

os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
}

os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
}

tags {
    environment = "staging"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html). To fill the terraform "storage_image_reference" part you can use the Azure CLI to get the information. So for example:

```
az vm image list --offer linux-data-science-vm --all --output table
```

Or

```
az vm image list --offer windows-data-science-vm --all --output table
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of SKUs and Offers for the Azure Data Science VM.

Windows Server 2016 edition: offer=windows-data-science-vm sku=windows2016

Ubuntu edition: offer=linux-data-science-vm-ubuntu sku=linuxdsvmubuntu

Windows Server 2012 edition: offer=standard-data-science-vm sku=standard-data-science-vm

CentOS edition: offer=linux-data-science-vm sku=linuxdsvm

Publisher for all these is microsoft-ads